# 500 Internal Server error for only 2 links

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am getting this error for only 2 links in the site

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

These links work fine in development environment. Error is only when deployed in server. The pages are there in the folder along with many other pages which doesn't raise this error. There's no difference in these pages.

I can't figure out whats causing this issue and only for 2 pages.

I checked the log files in \inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 and found nothing helpful.

Comment: You should also check the Windows Event Log.

Comment: I did. No warnings or errors